# Starred Score in Super Mario World

Tags: super-mario-world

When your save file reaches a score of **`96`** in Super Mario World, the score becomes **`*96`**, with a little star on it. What does this mean? Is it possible to get a higher score than **`96`**? Or get multiple stars?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have taken those steroids.

Comment: You mean staroids? lol

Comment: I giggled at that and now I feel bad....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are 96 exits in Super Mario World. The star signifies that you have done all of the levels.

More recent Mario games (like New Super Mario Bros. DS, and Super Mario Bros. Wii) have multiple stars available for completing different goals (beating the game. collecting all the coins, finding all the exits...), but Super Mario World only has one star.

Interesting fact:
In the Japanese Super Mario Bros. the number of completed levels is written in Japanese, unless you get to 96. At 96, it just displays the number "96" in our number system. (no star)

Comment: I'd also point out that the * doesn't show up in the "Super Mario All Stars + Super Mario World" combination cartridge, which also has some other changes including having 4 save slots for the Super Mario World game, and some new sprites for Luigi.

Answer (score 0):

It means you got all exits in the game. No, you cannot get more stars.

However, this only applies to the North American release. In Japanese release, there is no star (so the game doesn't even notice you got all exits). In European release, the 96 is blue without a star.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you dont have to complete all the star lvls you just have to get to the Mid Bottom lvl and find the secret door then complete the SUPER STAR lvls.

Comment: Sure, you need that secret exit, but you also expected to complete the other star levels (including the secret exits and the standard exits of each one).